# process inferior-lisp not running

Tags: emacs, common-lisp, sbcl

I installed sbcl

> sudo apt-get install sbcl

then loaded quicklisp

> sbcl --load ~/Downloads/quicklisp.lisp

then ran the installation command for installing quicklisp

> `(quicklisp-quickstart:install)`

added quicklisp to my init file

> `(ql:add-to-init-file)`

and then installed slime

> `(ql:quickload "quicklisp-slime-helper")`

which then printed out:

`(load (expand-file-name "~/quicklisp/slime-helper.el"))
;; Replace "sbcl" with the path to your implementation
(setq inferior-lisp-program "sbcl")`

Which I dutifully copied to my Emacs initialization file.

Upon running <kbd>M-x</kbd><kbd>slime</kbd> I got the following error:

> Searching for program: No such file or directory, sbcl

so I changed `inferior-lisp-program` to "/usr/bin/sbcl" as such:

```
(setq inferior-lisp-program "/usr/bin/sbcl")
```

Now, when I run <kbd>M-x</kbd><kbd>slime</kbd> I get:

> Process inferior-lisp not running

and in ielm when I enter `inferior-lisp-program` I get

```
ELISP> inferior-lisp-program
"/usr/bin/sbcl"
```

So I am all out of ideas of what I might have gone wrong. This is a new install by me, and I have used Common Lisp and SBCL in the past with no hiccups. What did I screw up?

edit:
It turns out I was getting this information in the `**Inferior Lisp**` buffer:

> emacs: /usr/bin/sbcl: No such file or directory
>
> Process inferior-lisp exited abnormally with code 127

Comment: Does it help if you kill the `*Inferior Lisp*` buffer before you try to run `slime` again?

Comment: I checked the output of the `**Inferior Lisp**` buffer and added that information to the post. I don't understand why it doesn't see /usr/bin/sbcl... I have launched it directly from that path with no issue on the command line.

Comment: And you are sure that it's not mistyped anywhere (control characters anywhere?) and that Emacs is running on the same host? Maybe add some details to the question to prove that these issues are not there.

Comment: Looks to me like there is no `/usr/bin/sbcl` program. I usually have mine installed in `/usr/local/bin/sbcl`

Comment: @RainerJoswig `apt-get` would not install it in `/usr/local`.

Comment: I am not running linux, but are you sure you have `sbcl` as a executable in `/usr/bin/`? What does `which sbcl` gives you in a shell? Maybe `sbcl` is named `sbcl-64-anything` on yout plattform.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it is because I installed Emacs via Flatpak. Emacs installed via Ubuntu's default repository is able to use SBCL and other binaries.